# How to resolve react-video-js-player failing to load media

Tags: reactjs

Hello I am trying to use the react video js player but I am getting the error below:

`The media could not be loaded, either because the server or network failed or because the format is not supported.`

At first, I thought maybe it was the video type because Initially it was a **.mkvi** video I then changed to mp4 and still nothing I get the same error can I please get help

**Code Below: VideoList.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import VideoPlayer from 'react-video-js-player';


const VideoList = (props) =>{

    let videos = props.listVideos
    return(

        <div>
            {videos.map(video =>{
                return(

                    <div key={video.id}>
                        <h3>{video.lecturer}</h3>
                        <VideoPlayer src={video.video} width="720" height="420" playbackRates={[0.5, 1, 3.85, 16]}/>
                    

                    </div>

                )
            })}

        </div>
    )
}

export default VideoList
```

Comment: can you give the link to the video concerned?

Comment: I am grabbing the video from my Django Api

Comment: Again, can you give the link to the video concerned? Typically this error will occur if the video is not existing, has issues with the encoding, file extension, etc. See this [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-wu-junjs?file=/src/App.js) I've written. My guess is that `video.video` does not contain the correct link to the video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said on my comments, typically this error will occur if the video is not existing, has issues with the encoding, file extension, etc. See this [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-wu-junjs?file=/src/App.js) I've written.

In the end, I was correct and the `video.video` object was returning a relative path instead of an absolute path which resulted in an incorrect link.

Regarding the [OP's current solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63421472/8680805) for this issue, this is not an ideal architecture because it will probably fail when you deploy to production, switch domains, or even just switch ports. Concantenating your base url is fine (e.g., `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`) but I would have this variable as a single source of truth probably residing at a state at the topmost component or as an [environment variable](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/) so that anytime you change domains, ports, or IP you can simply change this variable and you won't have to go through all of your components 1 by 1.

---

Example implementation on Class based components:

Parent component:

```
state = {
    base_url: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/`, // local dev api
    // base_url: `https://production-server:80/api/` // live site api

    // or an environment variable as described on my answer
}
```

Child component:

```
<VideoPlayer src={`${this.props.base_url}${content.video}`}
```

Answer (score 1):

So I managed to find the problem behind this, so I was getting data from the API but when I tried to access the video the API was not giving the full URL that is:

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/lectures/<here_the_name_of_the_lecture_video>`

But the API was giving me a relative path `media/lectures/<here_the_name_of_the_lecture_video>`

So I had to give the remaining the URL that which the API does not give when I render in the video i.e I had to write the following

`` <VideoPlayer src={`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api${content.video}`} ``

**So I am wondering**

Currently, this solution works but is this solution technically good? Because I am to believe that the API should be giving everything that I need I just have to make requests.

Can you please assist me to come up with a more technically viable solution for this problem